# Why is Python script reading files much faster the second run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime

I read the first line of a couple hundred text files with Python.
This runs under a couple seconds on the first time, but it takes only milliseconds to run the second time!!
Why is that ? Is it python ? Is it the operating system (Windows 7 in my case) ?

Here is the script:

```
import glob
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now()

for summary in glob.glob(r"C:\folder\*.txt"):
    with open(summary) as f:
        line = f.readline()
        print line.rstrip().decode('utf-16')

print 'Time: ', datetime.now()-start
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the [disk cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the operating system.

Answer (score 5):

It's the operating system. Modern OSes use disk caches to speed up repeated reads.

Answer (score 4):

Your operating system probably cached the data from disk after the first run. Restart your computer and see how the run time compares.